# Get modified fields on update with Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, profiling, sql-update

I am trying to catch the ZEND update in order to see who has modified what.
I have found the function update in ZEND framework sources. Like this

```
public function update($table, array $bind, $where = '')
{
    global $Profiling;
    try 
    {
        return $this->dbInstance->update($table, $bind,$where);
    }
    catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
        $this->write_log($Profiling,"update " . $table,$e);
    }
}
```

So I have the table, I have the where. And all the fields. Perfect.
But, there is a problem, when I do a print_r on $bind variable. I have all fields displayed.

```
Array
(
    [mail] => Test_Droit_Utilisateur@osef.com
    [lastName] => testlastname
    [firstName] => TestFirstName
    [v_gender_id] => 2
    [active] => 1
    [adress] => 56 rue test
)
```

I dont know what has been modified really. All data are posted by a form on an edition page. For example, when I modified only the mail for example, the print_r will display all the information in the $bind variable. Impossible to know what has been really modified.
I suppose I can make a while on fields and compare each field value to this $bind variable. But not very efficient because of on severals tables, I have a lot of fields.

If someone can help me to find a solution. I am ready :)
Thx everyone for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
array_diff_assoc($bind,$valuesfromDatabase);
```